# Duda operador de entrada ">>"

Tags: c++

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
CLliga::CarregaDades(const char* nomFitxer)
{
ifstream  fitxer(nomFitxer);

    if (fitxer.is_open())
    {
        int i = 0;
      (1)  fitxer >> m_numJornadas;

        delete[] m_pJornadas;

        m_pJornadas = new CJornada[m_numJornadas];

        for(i=0; i<m_numJornadas; i++)
        {
        (2)   fitxer >> m_pJornadas[i];
        }
        fitxer.close();
    }
}
```

Mi duda esta tanto en (1) como en (2), se que llama un operador ubicado en otra clase, pero no entiendo que hace exactamente una vez en el operador.¿Guarda en una variable fitxer el valor de numjornadas y después la sobrescribe con los valores del array m_pJornadas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ifstream  fitxer(nomFitxer);
```

Crea un *file stream* con el nombre pasado como argumento. Abre un archivo, vamos.

Si dicho archivo ha sido abierto correctamente ...

```
fitxer >> m_numJornadas;
```

No se observa la declaración de `m_numJornadas`, pero, de las siguientes líneas, deducimos que es un `int` (o similar; una variable numérica, vamos).

Esa línea **lee** un número del archivo anteriormente abierto.

```
delete[] m_pJornadas;
m_pJornadas = new CJornada[m_numJornadas];
```

`m_pJornadas` es un *puntero*, del tipo `CJornada *`;

Las líneas anteriores *liberan* el bloque de memoria previamente apuntado por `m_pJornadas`, y **asignan** un bloque de memoria nuevo, con capacidad para contener `m_numJornadas` (cuyo valor obtuvimos previamente del archivo).

```
fitxer >> m_pJornadas[i];
```

Dentro del bucle, va *llenando* el bloque de memoria reservado antes con los datos de `CJornada`s que vamos obteniendo del archivo.

En resumen: abre el archivo, lee el número de elementos a leer, asigna memória para dicho número de elementos, y los va leyendo y colocando en el *susodicho* bloque de memória.

Teníamos una lista de elementos, y la reemplazamos con una lista de elementos nueva.

**EDITO**

Para responder a los comentarios:

#### ¿ Que le indica que linea del documento leer ?

Empieza por el principio; se lee justo después de abrirlo, así que comienza por el *byte* 1 del archivo.

La primera lectura, salvo que el operador `ifstream::operator>>( )` esté reescrito, lee un entero; ¿ tamaño ? Hasta que llegue a `\n`.

#### ¿ Cada cuanto baja a la siguiente linea?

Como está leyendo `CJornada`s, **no lo sabemos**; no sabemos si es un `typedef` de algún tipo básico, o una clase propia. En este último caso, puede haber definido el `ofstream::operator>>( std::ofstream &, CJornada & )`, con lo que puede leer de la forma que dicha clase estime conveniente: *byte* a *byte*, línea a línea (hasta el `\n`), de 300 en 300 *bytes*, ...

Comment: Gracias me ha quedado bastante mas claro, excepto en el operador ¿que le indica que linea del documento leer, cada cuanto baja a la siguiente linea?

Comment: @ElPatrón Respuesta editada.